# Can the frequency of a Pandas tseries DatetimeIndex be preserved when writing to an HDFStore?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, pytables, hdf

I have a Pandas DataFrame in which the index is (notice the Freq: H) -

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-12-31 23:00:00]
Length: 26304, Freq: H, Timezone: None
```

There are multiple columns but the first few rows (and others scattered throughout) have all NA entries.  If I write this to a HDF file thus:

```
hdfstore.put('/table', df, format='table', data_columns=True, append=False)
```

and then read it back with:

```
df = hdfstore['/table']
```

and look at the index, I see:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-11 04:00:00, ..., 2013-12-31 23:00:00]
Length: 24656, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Notice that the Freq is now None and also that there are less rows and a later start date-time.  The first row is now the first row of the original DataFrame that contains at least one non-NA column value.

Firstly, is this expected behaviour due to limitations of the HDF5 format and how DataFrames are stored, or a bug?

Is there a clean way to avoid this happening, or do I just need to 'fix' up the index after load.  Not sure what the best way to do that is either.

Comment: One quick-and-dirty work-around is to just add a dummy column containing all 0s.  Then, upon reload, the Freq of the DatetimeIndex is preserved.  Obviously, that has unnecessary storage overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is an option introduced in 0.13.1 (might have been 0.13.0), where you can set `dropna=False` on a `put/append` to avoid dropping an all-NaN row. This is done for efficiency, as most of the time in say storing a Panel, you have lots of all-NaN rows, but no reason to store them.

Otherwise the frequency information will be preserved. Note that if you are `appending` the frequency information will NOT be preserved if you append multiple times.

You can always `pd.infer_freq(an_index)` if you need to re-infer the freqency (if possible). Normally this is done automatically in any event if needed.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - works like a charm (0.13.1).  Now to documented it.

Comment: docs are here (for a different function), and the docstring: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#multiple-table-queries. Would welcome a short blurb maybe in the beginning sections where table format is mentioned (in a warning/notes block). PR pls!